# How to fix this OOP error?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to understand python oop. but it's not easy for me. thus i wrote
 python OOP program (ex.2) for below procedural program (ex.1) but It's not working with below error.

**ex.1**

```
def factorial(n):  
    num = 1   
    while n >= 1:  
        num = num * n  
        n = n - 1  
    return num   

f = factorial(3)  
print f # 6
```

**ex.2**

```
class factorial:

    def __init__(self):


      self.num = 1

    def fact(self,n):
        while n>=1:
            num = self.num * n
            n = n-1
        return num

f = factorial()
ne= factorial.fact(3)
print(ne)
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python test/oop test3.py", line 13, in ne= factorial.fact(3)
TypeError: fact() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the *instance* you created to call the method:

```
f = factorial() # creates instance of the factorial class
ne = f.fact(3)
```

Or to call using  the class itself without assignment:

```
ne = factorial().fact(3) # < parens ()
print(ne)
```

You also have a mistake you should be using `self.num` or you will always get 1 as the answer, so:

```
class Factorial: # uppercase
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1
    def fact(self, n):
        while n >= 1:
            self.num = self.num * n # change the attribute self.num
            n -= 1 # same as n  = n - 1
        return self.num
```

If you don't return your method will return None but you will still increment self.num so if you don't want to return but want to see the value of self.num after you call the method you can access the attribute directly:

```
class Factorial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1

    def fact(self, n):
        while n >= 1:
            self.num = self.num * n
            n -= 1

ne = Factorial()

ne.fact(5) # will update self.num but won't return it this time
print(ne.num) # access the attribute to see it
```

Comment: no worries,  not related but you should use uppercase for class names in python so Factorial. You can also use  `n -= 1`

Comment: Thank you so much!!... I will do it . .... I am trying to learn python oop. i think you will help me..How I can contact you?

Comment: you're welcome. check this out http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html it is a really great resource

Comment: @ireshanpathirana Seeing as padraic brought this (`n -= 1`) up, I'll just mention that it works the same with other operators, too. So with `*`, you can also do `self.num *= n`.

Comment: @ireshanpathirana, yes if you don't return calling the method will actually just return None.  You can change the value of sellf.num and not return .I will add an example

Comment: @ireshanpathirana, think of it like `list.sort`  or any other method that changes a value in place, we don't need to return something if we are just updating the original object.

Comment: Just a note: `factorial()` isn't the class itself, but a new instance of the class. You just don't save it in a variable before use. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems:
1) Logical error: `num = self.num * n` should be changed
 to `self.num = self.num * n`, Here num is another variable which you are creating.

2) Logical error, But If 1st one is addressed it becomes Syntax error:
 `return num` should be changed to `return self.num`

3) Syntax Error:

```
f = factorial()
ne= factorial.fact(3)
```

should be either changed to 
`ne = factorial().fact(3)` or `ne = f.fact(3)`

Comment: Thanak you dear   @kvivek